# HomeScreen function isnt working! Help pls

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use route in the main file to display homescreen on the page but homescreen as a function is nto working

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import data from '../data';

function HomeScreen(props) {
    return  <div>HomeScreen </div>
    // <ul className="products">
    //     {
    //         data.products.map(product => 
    //             <li>
    //                 <div className="product">
    //                     <Link to={"product/" + product._id}>
    //                     <img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt="product"/></Link>
    //                 </div>
    //                 <div className="product-name">
    //                     <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
    //                     <div className="product-price">{product.price}</div>
    //                     <div className="product-rating"> {product.rating} Stars {product.numReviews} Reviews</div>
    //                 </div>
    //             </li>) 
    //     }
    // </ul>
    
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

here is where i try to utilise the functions but none seem to appear on the page, only thing shown on the page are the contents in the main (app.js) file

```
        <main className="main">
            <div className="content">
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
                <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomeScreen} />  
              </Routes>
        </div>
      </main>
```

here is the remaining code

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './Screens/ProductScreen';


function App() {

  const openMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add("open");
  }
  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove("open");
  }
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="grid-container ">
        <header className="header">
            <div className="brand">
                <button onClick={openMenu}>
                    &#9776;
                </button>
                <Link to="/"> Uni Store</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="header-links">
                <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
                <a href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <aside className="sidebar">
            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <button className="sidebar-close-button" onClick={closeMenu}>x</button>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Hoodies</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Joggers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Shoes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <main className="main">
            <div className="content">
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
                <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomeScreen} />  
              </Routes>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer className="footer">
        All rights reserved. 
    </footer>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please add more info, what is not working ? any error ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: no error, just blank. When i look at the react app its like the homescreen function isnt being used.

Comment: you should add all the related code, we have zero idea without seeing your code !

Comment: added everything now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [React router V6](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/tutorial) to render an element / component you should be using `element` prop instead of `component` and also `exact` prop is not needed to my knowledge ...

```
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomeScreen} />  
          </Routes>
```

should be

```
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
            <Route path="/" element ={<HomeScreen />} />  
          </Routes>
```